# I've lost SuperSu

Tags: rooting, stock-android, nexus-5

I have a rooted [nexus-5](/questions/tagged/nexus-5) but the only problem is I don't have the SuperSu application on my device. I have tried to re-flash the zip but that doesn't do anything. Its in my application list in the settings but It's not in the app drawer. It was there before but somehow it just disappeared. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The binaries should still be there so just install it again. Updates sometimes make the icon vanish, but it's still there. Do you have the APK file anywhere or is it purchased?

Answer (score 3):

## **`eu.chanfire.supersu.mainactivity-xxxxx`**

(**xxxxx** would be the SuperSU icon you picked).

*If that activity is disabled/restricted it will remove the icon from the app drawer.*

---

Since rooted you should use the app [My Android Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools&hl=en) to check.

- From menu select **`Activity`**
- Select the **`System tab`**
- Scroll down to **`SuperSu`** app
- Select it and look for disabled main activity
- Enable the activity

***It is safe to enable this activity for just this instance. Don't go through the list of apps and start enabling and/or disabling things without understanding what they do. You can brick your device. You do so on your own. And always make a backup before changing anything***

As I stated above, if the **`MainActivity-xxxxx`** is disabled it will remove the icon from your app drawer. This is the cause of the disappearing icon.

---

I have checked this myself on each of my devices. Disabling and enabling activity for SuperSU, then checking app drawer for the icon each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in applications but not in the app drawer just reinstall it from the playstore. Also make sure your launcher isn't hiding the app icon, which is a possibility depending on what launcher you use. Also in the supersu app under customizations launch icon, there is a setting to hide the icon. If you want to make sure the binaries are still there you can always check easily with an app called Root Verifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening dialer then type `*#*#1234#*#*`
If you cannot see the asterisks, please read below:

(Asterisk, hashtag, asterisk, hashtag, one, two, three, four, hastag, asterisk, hashtag, asterisk)

It should open SuperSU
Then Change SuperSU icon on the SuperSU settings